# How to handle Multiple Results by Using the DataReader in Visual C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, sqldatareader

I have a stored procedure which returns two tables. Table 1 has for example {1,2,3,4,5}, the table 2 will have have {a,b,c,d,e}. For example {1,a}, {2,b} similarly all are related.

In my reader, I have to read all these data into a List. Object will have have two properties where {1,a} go. This is the code I have now,

```
while(reader.Read())
        {
            Transaction transaction = null;
            transactions.Add(transaction = new Transaction()
            {
                TranID = reader.GetInt64(reader.GetOrdinal("TranID"))
            });

            if (reader.NextResult())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    transaction.Amounts.Add(new Fund
                    {
                        Amount = reader.GetDecimal(reader.GetOrdinal("Amount")),
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

What's happening here is if I return 10 Transaction Ids and  10 Amounts, my final result has only 1 Transaction and 10 Amounts mapped to it. How do I get 10 Transactions with equivalent Amount?

Comment: I think it would be better to change the stored procedure to return a single result set instead of two.

Comment: Is there no other way to do this?

Comment: There probably are other ways to do it, but from the way you described the tables you get back, how can you be sure that it's {1, a}, {2, b} and not {1, a, b}, {2, c}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access multiple resultsets this way from SqlDataReader. You can access all the rows from one resultset at a time. If you move to the nextresult set, you can not go back to the previous result set.

Following is the sample code of how you retrieve data from multiple resultsets of SqlDataReader.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
     Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
}

if (reader.NextResult())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
    }
}
```